# Where is question about pairing headphone to TV on topic?

Tags: support, asking-questions

I am having a problem pairing a beats headphone with my Samsung TV. It worked a couple of months ago, I lent them to my son who used them with different devices and now the TV doesn't see them. No problem with my Mac or iPhone. Where is this on-topic?

Comment: Not here, unfortunately. Have you [talked to the manufacturer](https://www.beatsbydre.com/support/how-to/bluetooth-troubleshooting)?

Comment: If "here" is EE, I knew that. Is there no relevant stackexchange site for consumer electronics?

Comment: Not that I know of. There are plenty of other platforms on the Web for that sort of thing.

Comment: Why is asking where something is on topic is stackexchange, in meta, so down-votable?

Comment: In meta, downvotes don't mean you did something bad; they just mean that a person disagrees -- it's more of an answer than anything else.

Comment: I hate to be thick but how do you disagree with a question?

Comment: Downvotes for anything really on Meta won't affect your main score on our SE. It may indicate disagreement and it also may indicate irrelevancy. In this case, it's probably the latter. Asking _where to ask something_ isn't the mission on our Meta. This Meta is about _our_ Electrical Engineering StackExchange website. It's entirely possible that there is absolutely no StackExchange website will consider this on-topic and it could be because the website doesn't want to affiliate itself with that topic (in this case, consumerism).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's on topic at the respective company's customer support.